# Create matrix from a pre-ordered vectors in r

Tags: r

How can I create a matrix that will contain the sales values:

```
 summary(sales.dp)
      Dept            Week           Sales     
 Min.   : 1.00   8      :  81   Min.   :  -545.8  
 1st Qu.:21.00   9      :  81   1st Qu.:  2794.9  
 Median :42.00   11     :  81   Median :  7840.9  
 Mean   :45.93   19     :  81   Mean   : 14444.1  
 3rd Qu.:72.00   3      :  80   3rd Qu.: 19309.3  
 Max.   :99.00   6      :  80   Max.   :242627.6  
                 (Other):3625
```

so that each Sales will appear in row Dept and in column Week?

All missing values will be represented by NA

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
with(sales.dp, tapply(Sales, list(Dept, Week), mean))
```

If a week:Dept pair has multiple sales, this will take the average, otherwise the single value (and absence of sales is represented by NA)